# The version "latest" couldn't be reached, there are no registered migrations

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, database-migration

So I'm setting up a Symfony 5 project and running the following commands to generate the database from entity annotations like this:

```
php bin/console doctrine:schema:validate
php bin/console doctrine:migrations:diff
php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate
```

But it's not working as expected, and instead I'm just getting this error:

```
**[ERROR]** The version "latest" couldn't be reached, there are no registered migrations.
```

The **diff** command correctly generates the migration file containing the **up()** and **down()** functions however when I subsequently run the **migrate** command to generate the database it fails with the above error.

I also notice the file /config/packages/doctrine_migrations.yml has changed recently to this:

```
doctrine_migrations:
    migrations_paths:
        'App\Migrations': '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Migrations'
```

However it appears doctrine is looking outside this path for the migrations in the following path:

```
'%kernel.project_dir%/migrations'
```

How do you resolve the above error so that the **migrate** command works as expected and generates the database tables from the generated migration file?

php bin/console debug:config doctrine_migrations

```
Current configuration for extension with alias "doctrine_migrations"
=================================================================    ===

doctrine_migrations:
    migrations_paths:
        App\Migrations: /var/www/src/Migrations
    services: {  }
    factories: {  }
    storage:
        table_storage:
            table_name: null
            version_column_name: null
            version_column_length: null
            executed_at_column_name: null
            execution_time_column_name: null
    migrations: {  }
    connection: null
    em: null
    all_or_nothing: false
    check_database_platform: true
    custom_template: null
    organize_migrations: false
```

Comment: So the database has not yet been created?

Comment: @ArleighHix It is definitely created.

Comment: With `php bin/console doctrine:database:create`?

Comment: No manually, with create database <DATABASE_NAME>;

Comment: Is your indentation in ` /config/packages/doctrine_migrations.yml` correct, cause what you copied seems wrong.

Comment: @JulienB. Updated indentation.

Comment: can you post the output of `php bin/console debug:config doctrine_migrations`?

Comment: @JulienB. Added that above.

Comment: Where are the migrations files on the filesystem? Are they in `/var/www/src/Migrations`? Also, what is the namespace on top of the files?

Comment: @JulienB. Migrations are at "/var/www/src/Migrations" with namespace "App\Migrations".

Comment: However it appears doctrine is looking outside this path for the migrations in the following path: '%kernel.project_dir%/migrations' ... What makes you think that?

Answer (score 11):

Check the namespace of your migration scripts and the config of the migration bundle. After moving the directory from `src/migrations` to `migrations` you have to change the namespace of the files to `DoctrineMigrations` and change the storage table name to the one, which exists (otherwise the new default migration table name is `doctrine_migration_versions`).

Here is my proposal:
some migration file in /migrations

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace DoctrineMigrations;

use Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\Schema;
use Doctrine\Migrations\AbstractMigration;

// ...
```

Config:

```
doctrine_migrations:
    migrations_paths:
        # namespace is arbitrary but should be different from App\Migrations
        # as migrations classes should NOT be autoloaded
        'DoctrineMigrations': '%kernel.project_dir%/migrations'

    storage:
        # Default (SQL table) metadata storage configuration
        table_storage:
            table_name: 'migration_versions'
```

this helps me to setup the project from scratch with Symfony5 and be backwards compatible with the current running production system.

Answer (score 6):

I think you need to run the command `"php bin/console make:migration"` before `"php bin/console make:migration:migrate"`

I hope this is helpful.

Comment: This command only works if you have installed the dependency symfony/maker-bundle

Answer (score 0):

I just want to add an info because I was stuck for too long.

I updated my database, but I forgot to update `server_version` in `config/packages/doctrine.yaml`. When I corrected it, the error disappeared.